# Quarkas - Unable to build - Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempted to mix @NativeImageTest

Tags: java, unit-testing, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to figure out why running a `./mvnw package` is leading to the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempted to mix @NativeImageTest and JVM mode tests in the same test run. This is not allowed.
```

I am trying to build up towards a native image and I added the extension to my simple test case as the documentation refers to https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image. However when I create a new test class which extends my base and add `@NativeImageTest` I get the exception above. I have not messed with the generate pom so am not sure if I am missing a step or not. This also happens if I execute `./mvnw package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true`

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the documentation https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image#excluding-tests-when-running-as-a-native-executable and try to add `@DisabledOnNativeImage` annotation to the test you extended the native test from.